# Duplicate powerpoint slides (text and formatting) with officeR

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

I would like to create additional slides in my R generate powerpoint presentation that are exact duplicates of some other slide of the same powerpoint presentation.
Is there any function of officeR that does so?

Reading the officeR package documentation I just found add_slide that only creates a slide with a particular layout and thus does not include all the texts/images that are on the actual slide, unless they are hardcoded in the slide layout.

Many thanks!